# Can't figure out a regex with line break - HTML

Tags: html, css, regex

I have written a very simple regular expression to search within an HTML document for any  tag - as we are modifying 40+ templates that have been edited by a WYSIWYG editor that was horrible. Basically, it added style="font... tags everywhere - so I want to delete them all.

The problem is, some of them have line breaks between the styles (like you would typically write CSS) - and I can't figure out how to include line breaks within my expression.

Here is what I have:

```
style="font(.*?)"
```

I am using textmate to search for it, and it works great except for styles that have hard line breaks in them.

Any help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this RegEx: `style="font([\s\S]*?)"`. `.` does not match `\n` by default.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked perfect. I'll accept your answer as soon as I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `(?s)` at the front of your regex causes . to match newline as well

Comment: Depends on the language.

Comment: Only isn't supported in ruby and JavaScript so should work in this case

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward way to do it:

```
style="font([^"]*)"
```